# how to control datagridview cursor movement in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'd like my datagridview cursor to move right to the next column instead of moving to the next row after entering data to a cell.

I've attempted to take control of the cursor by capturing the keys via dataGridView1_KeyDown event but this does not prevent the cursor from moving to the next row after entering data to a cell ...

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Cheers,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are an answer from Mark Rideout (DatagridView Program Manager)

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=157055&SiteID=1

Scroll down 4 posts (and then more because they make better versions later on in the thread).

For future references if link will expire (**All credits to Mark Rideout**):

Create a new class named dvg that inherits from DataGridView. Compile project and then use this extended Datagridview-control instead of the normal and you'll have a datagridview that selects the next cell when pressing enter:

```
public class dgv : DataGridView
{
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    Keys key = (keyData & Keys.KeyCode);
    if (key == Keys.Enter)
    {
        return this.ProcessRightKey(keyData);
    }
    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        return this.ProcessRightKey(e.KeyData);
    }
    return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe I am not  competent to comment but Should be better to use return this.ProcessTabKey(e.KeyData); instead of this.ProcessRightKey(e.KeyData); Like that We can go to new line if there is no beside column in  current row